# UICollectionView ImageView Problems

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I got some serious problems with my collectionview.
So I fetch async. some data from an api and set the data variable, than I reload my collectionview. My collectionview contains basicly some cells with data from the api and one cell extra with a plus icon. The cells shape and layout is the same, so I used the same collectionviewcell class for both.

I calculate my number of items like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return data.count + 1
}
```

And do my cell stuff like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OverviewUserCell

  if(indexPath.row == data.count) {
    cell.userImageView.image = UIImage(named: "plus")!
    //some additional coloring and stuff
  } else {
    cell.userImageView.image = UIImage(named: "oma")!
    //some additional coloring and stuff
  }
  cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds
  cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]
  cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8

  return cell
}
```

My cell itself contains a round image and a Label:

```
class OverviewUserCell: UICollectionViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var userImageView: UIImageView!

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.makeItCircle()
  }

  func makeItCircle() {
    self.userImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.userImageView.layer.cornerRadius  = CGFloat(roundf(Float(self.userImageView.frame.size.height/2.0)))
  }

}
```

Somehow (maybe because different image sizes) the frame of the imageview changes, or something like this, because the plus image is not round, but I want it to stay the same. I added constraints to every element in the cell. If I don't load the data, the image is perfectly round, but when the data is loaded and the collectionview reloaded, the plus image is not round anymore.

The images should be same sized and same position.

Comment: Try adding `clipsToBounds = true` to your `makeItCircle` function

Comment: That does not work. @kye

Comment: `CGFloat(roundf(Float(self.userImageView.frame.size.height/2.0)))` might be your problem. There's no need to round or convert to `CGFloat`. Try `frame.size.width / 2` and `clipToBounds`

Comment: Causes still the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting corner radius of cell, try setting corner radius of UIImageView. But before that make sure that your UIImage view should have height equal to width.

And before setting imageview.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
add this line: imageview.layoutIfNeeded();

Comment: As you can see in my pictures, the cornerRadius for the cell is also wanted, but the problem is just at the imageview. I use autolayout to size my imageview. LayoutIfNeeded() does not make any difference!

Comment: Can you tell me what constrainrs u have added to uiimageview?

Comment: Yes, added them to the post as an image!

Comment: This happens mainly because at the time of calculation corner radius, we do not have updated height and width of image view. Better you write imageview.layoutIfNeeded() before setting corner radius of image

Comment: That fixed it! So basicly because I used ratio in my constraints the calculation is at runtime and I need to call layoutIfNeeded() to calc it?